# Joint PDF involving independent exponential random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent exponential random variables with parameters $a$ and $b$ respectively. Let $U=\min(X,Y)$ and $$V=\begin{cases}1,& U=X\\ 0,& U=Y.\end{cases}$$ Find the joint distribution of $(U,V)$.

Since the rv's are just exponential, then the distribution of $U$ is also exponential with parameter $a+b$. Also, $P(U = X)=P(X < Y)= \frac a{a+b}$ and $P(U=Y)=P(Y < X)=\frac b{a+b}$.

However, I cannot seem to use these info to come up with the joint distribution of $U$ and $V$. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you find $\Pr(\text{min is }X \mid U=u)$ and $\Pr(\text{min is }Y \mid U=u)$, i.e. can you find $\Pr(V=1 \mid U=u)$ and $\Pr(V=0 \mid U=u)$?

Comment: You can show  $P(V=1|U=u)=P(V=1)$ using the quality unique to exponential RVs.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that the joint distribution of $(U,V)$ is described by the joint "density" $f_{U,V}$ which satisfies $$\mathbb P(U\leqslant u, V=v) = \int_{-\infty}^u f_{U,V}(t,v)\ \mathsf dt.$$
Morever, we have $$f_{U,V}(u,v) = \mathbb P(V=v\mid U=u)f_U(u). $$
We compute
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(V=1\mid U=u) &= \mathbb P(X<Y\mid X\wedge Y=u)\\
&= \frac{f_X(u)(1-F_Y(u))}{F_{X\wedge Y}(u)}\\
&= \frac{ae^{-au}e^{-bu}}{(a+b)e^{-(a+b)u}}\\
&= \frac a{a+b}.
\end{align}
It follows that
$$\mathbb P(V=0\mid U=u) = 1 - \mathbb P(V=1\mid U=u) = 1 - \frac a{a+b} = \frac b{a+b}, $$
and therefore for $u\in(0,\infty)$,
\begin{align}
f_{U,V}(u,v) &=\begin{cases}\frac b{a+b}(a+b)e^{-(a+b)u},& v=0\\ \frac a{a+b}(a+b)e^{-(a+b)u},& v=1 \end{cases}\\\\
&=((1-v)b+va)e^{-(a+b)u}.
\end{align}

Comment: This can't be the right answer since in your calculation $P(V=1|U=u)\to 0$ as $u\to \infty$ and that can't be right. The answer is $P(V=1|U=u)=\frac a {a+b}$, because of memorylessness and $P(V=1)=\frac a {a+b}$

Comment: @A.S. Thanks, I'll correct it.